# Deconfigure RAID1 and mount the second hard drive in Debian

Tags: debian, mount, hard-disk, raid, automounting

The dedicated server running on Debian has two 512 SSDs, both part of a single RAID1 disk array. There are many guides for that without losing any data on the disk but could not find the complete one in order to deconfigure RAID1, format one of the disks, mount them and configure in `/etc/fstab`.

If someone provides a complete guide, that be very useful for new Unix users like me.

These are the results of some commands.

```
# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0   477G  0 disk
├─sda1    8:1    0    32G  0 part
│ └─md0   9:0    0    32G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─sda2    8:2    0   512M  0 part
│ └─md1   9:1    0 511.4M  0 raid1 /boot
└─sda3    8:3    0 444.4G  0 part
  └─md2   9:2    0 444.3G  0 raid1 /
sdb       8:16   0   477G  0 disk
├─sdb1    8:17   0    32G  0 part
│ └─md0   9:0    0    32G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─sdb2    8:18   0   512M  0 part
│ └─md1   9:1    0 511.4M  0 raid1 /boot
└─sdb3    8:19   0 444.4G  0 part
  └─md2   9:2    0 444.3G  0 raid1 /


# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdb: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0ba4900f

Device     Boot    Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1           2048   67110911  67108864    32G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2       67110912   68159487   1048576   512M fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb3       68159488 1000213167 932053680 444.4G fd Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sda: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x31fd01ce

Device     Boot    Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1           2048   67110911  67108864    32G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2       67110912   68159487   1048576   512M fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3       68159488 1000213167 932053680 444.4G fd Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/md0: 32 GiB, 34326183936 bytes, 67043328 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/md1: 511.4 MiB, 536281088 bytes, 1047424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/md2: 444.3 GiB, 477077241856 bytes, 931791488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


# blkid
/dev/sdb1: UUID="4374a69b-c5ca-ceee-bfd3-3df61d255a13" UUID_SUB="f1ca2293-d87d-83b8-dad9-aba968c25d0a" LABEL="rescue:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="0ba4900f-01"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="4b93d869-e581-7187-70ca-c4f9e7668ed5" UUID_SUB="6921e275-a6f3-0e5f-52c6-37520265266e" LABEL="rescue:1" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="0ba4900f-02"
/dev/sdb3: UUID="10c95f64-534c-e940-f016-77851637282b" UUID_SUB="003339b6-34c6-a11c-0f95-722934e2cd25" LABEL="rescue:2" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="0ba4900f-03"
/dev/sda1: UUID="4374a69b-c5ca-ceee-bfd3-3df61d255a13" UUID_SUB="865a9479-0077-b93e-fde5-62b4427eed93" LABEL="rescue:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="31fd01ce-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="4b93d869-e581-7187-70ca-c4f9e7668ed5" UUID_SUB="fade36f5-1a58-9645-4c8e-d3bbbadb2d4d" LABEL="rescue:1" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="31fd01ce-02"
/dev/sda3: UUID="10c95f64-534c-e940-f016-77851637282b" UUID_SUB="75c16690-bce6-0f66-1a6f-4819b70fb1bd" LABEL="rescue:2" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="31fd01ce-03"
/dev/md0: UUID="2317882d-d15e-4879-8eab-8d37b77b717e" TYPE="swap"
/dev/md1: UUID="6ef84344-8aa2-4807-9486-4c98ab3aeffa" TYPE="ext3"
/dev/md2: UUID="a710dcc5-e25f-452b-bffd-486bb9eba812" TYPE="ext4"
```

And this is `/etc/fstab`:

```
proc /proc proc defaults 0 0
/dev/md/0 none swap sw 0 0
/dev/md/1 /boot ext3 defaults 0 0
/dev/md/2 / ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: this only works for RAID 1 which is a simple linear mirror.

Removing one drive from a RAID array:

```
mdadm /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sdb1
mdadm /dev/md0 --remove /dev/sdb1
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdb1
```

Same accordingly for all other md / sdb partitions. Then you can do whatever you like with `/dev/sdb`.

As for the RAID, it's degraded (1 out of 2 drives). It's possible to make it not degraded (1 out of 1 drive):

```
mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --raid-devices=1 --force
```

That way the RAID layer still exists without really doing anything. But it leaves you the option to easily add a second drive in the future, thus resuming RAID operations. And there is no need to change any other configurations.

---

If you want to get rid of RAID 1 altogether, you would have to determine the data offset and then move the partition offset accordingly.

```
# mdadm --examine /dev/sda1
Data Offset : 2048 sectors
$ cat /sys/block/sda/sda1/start
2048
$ cat /sys/block/sda/sda1/size
268613632
```

In this example, you have a data offset of `2048`, the partition itself starts at `2048` and is `268613632` large.

You have to remove this partition and create a new partition `2048+2048` - `268613632-2048`. I.e. increase start by offset sectors and reduce size by offset sectors, so the end sector of the partition remains unchanged.

You can do this with any partitioner of your choice, in `parted` it would be:

```
# parted /dev/sda
) unit s
) print free
) rm 1
) print free
) mkpart primary 4096s 268611583s
) name 1 mynonraidroot
```

After a reboot, the new partition should now point to the filesystem directly, and the RAID itself would no longer exist. (If you do this step from a rescue system, you won't need to reboot, either, and you can also `mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda1` before changing the partition, assuming you have already stopped the RAID).

---

In a final step, you'd have to remove `mdadm.conf`, update bootloader and initramfs to get rid of any remaining references to the RAID setup.